# Java : JDBC Connection Issue When Click On Button

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm facing a problem in this program there are two `GUI's`.When user click on button it checks for a database connection when connection become successful then second `GUI` appear which has `JComboBox`. But the problem is it doesn't show the catalogs of `mysql` in `JComboBox`.
Main Method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Gui obj = new Gui();



    }

}
```

First Gui

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    Connector c = new Connector();

    private JButton b1;

    public Gui() {

        b1 = new JButton("Click To Connect");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if (c.getConnect() == true) {
                    dispose();

                    new Gui2();
                }

            }

        });

        add(b1);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Connection Class

```
public class Connector {

    private Connection conn;

    public boolean getConnect() {

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "john", "root");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

        }

        if (conn == null) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");

            return false;
        }

        System.out.println("Connection Success");

        return true;

    }

}
```

ComboBox GUI

```
public class Gui2 extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox box;

    Connection connection;

    public Gui2() {

        box = new JComboBox();

        opencatalog();

        add(box);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void opencatalog() {

        try {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();

            ResultSet rs = meta.getCatalogs();

            List ct = new ArrayList();

            while (rs.next()) {

                ct.add(rs.getString(1));

            }

            rs.close();
            box.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ct.toArray()));

            box.setSelectedItem(connection.getCatalog());

            box.setEnabled(ct.size() > 0);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }
        box.setEnabled(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: where did you get the connection in `Gui2`.

Comment: Since you always call `box.setEnabled(false)`, how do you know what the JComboBox contains?

Comment: @Satya  I get the connection from Connector Class

Comment: I'm asking in `Gui2` class.

Comment: @VGR i want to say that the connection does not connect to JComboBox

Comment: @Satya there is Connector class which connect to Database but i don't know how to make this Connention to work with Gui2 class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Connector` class

change the `return` type to `Connection` and `return` `conn`.

```
public Connection getConnect() {

....
return conn
}
```

2. `Gui` class, change the condition

   ```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
               Connection conn= c.getConnect();  
               if (conn!=null) {
                   new Gui2(conn);//pass connection object here
                   dispose();
               }

           }
   ```
3. `Gui2` class, constructor should be

   ```
   public Gui2(Connection conn)
   {
      connection=conn;
      box = new JComboBox();
      .................
   }
   ```
4. `Gui2` class,

   ```
    box.setEnabled(true);//should be enabled,
   ```

Comment: connection=c.getConnect(); gives error because getConnect() method Return boolean

Comment: so change the `return` type to `Connection` and `return conn`.

Comment: remove that condition `c.getConnect()`

Comment: but the frame will be open i want that when button cick connection becomes true then it automatically open

Comment: Thanks for Help i understand